# cmake multiple executables errors in linking because of OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, googletest

Hi I want to make more executables for one project. I have tried some ways, but I cannot figure it out what is wrong.

For beginning, I want to make 2 executables: one for the project and one for the test with GoogleTest.

I have tried something like like:

```
if (CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT)
    add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${common_source_files_cpp})
    add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test ${common_source_test_files_cpp})

    ENABLE_TESTING()

    ADD_TEST(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test)

    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-static -lmysqlclient -lz -pthread -ldl -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_regex-mt")
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test "-lmysqlclient -lz -pthread -ldl -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_regex-mt")
endif()
```

But I get errors. So I have searched on the internet for another way and found [this example](https://github.com/dmonopoly/gtest-cmake-example)

I have tried to do like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

option(test "Build all tests." OFF)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME MyProj)

project(${EXECUTABLE_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

include_directories(src/main/cpp
            ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            )

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem 
                       system 
                       regex 
                       program_options
                                       )

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol
              src/main/cpp/main.cpp
              src/main/cpp/MyTypes.hpp

              src/main/cpp/MyFunc.cpp
              src/main/cpp/MyFunc.hpp
              )

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                            ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                            )

if (test)
  find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

  enable_testing()

  include_directories( ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                   )

  add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test 
                    src/test/cpp/test_Sol2.cpp
                            src/main/cpp/MyFunc.hpp
                    src/main/cpp/MyFunc.cpp
                    )


  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                             ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                             ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
                             pthread
                             )

  add_test(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test 
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test
          )

endif()
```

Now I am getting some kind of linking errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)':
gtest-all.cc:(.text+0xdd84): multiple definition of `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a(ts_gtest.cpp.o):ts_gtest.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal8GTestLogC2ENS0_16GTestLogSeverityEPKci+0x0): first defined here 
...
```

Can someone help me? What is the problem? What am I not doing well?

---

Ok, It says that the redefinition is in OpenCV. But if I remove one of OpenCV, or GTest I get errors like

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
...
```

Is there a way to resolve these redefinitions?

Comment: Are you showing the entire error? Also, this should be a hint: `multiple definition of <snip> GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)`

Comment: I understand it, but how to fix it? Where is the redefinition? Or how to avoid it?

Comment: It does not say where is the second definition is, so I can figgure out that I am doing two times a linking.

Comment: Is it possible because I have done the steps from [this link](http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/) and I have not verify if the files already exist?